# c - Network packet sniff + analyse

Tags: c, security, networking, tcp

I am writing a packet sniffer in C, capturing them using pcap.

I would like to know how to detected whether a packet is part of a christmas tree scan. My understanding is that by detecting if a packet's URG, PSH and FIN flag's (in the tcp header) are set, it indicates that it is. But using the code below, I haven't had much luck in making it work.

```
struct tcphdr *tcphdr = (struct tcphdr *) packet;
if(tcphdr->urg && tcphdr->psh && tcphdr->fin){
  printf("Christmas\n");
}
```

Any help towards this is would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked at your pcap in Wireshark?  Are those three bits actually set?  What library are you using to read the packets in C?  Is your entire goal to find which packets have these flags set, or is your real goal something else?

Comment: First you absolutely need to verify that you are actually receiving packets with these combination of TCP flags, use wireshark for that. The next step is to debug your code to make sure you are trying to decode the TCP segments correctly, e.g. are you looking at that right (TCP only) packets at the proper offset , accounting for the proper ethertype in the ethernet layer ant calculating the proper IP header length to get to the TCP header etc.